# How to plot candlestick chart with dates on xaxis using cufflinks?

Tags: python

I tried to plot a candlestick chart with dates on xaxis.
But the dates on chart is autoincrementing rather than using the dates used in dataframe.
Generally saturday, sunday dates are having no candles since no trading.

My output is also including these dates on chart and finally plotting the chart as white empty space for these dates.
These candles for the day will be present from 9:15 AM to 3:15 PM.
I need include the candles for these timings only.
But when I tried to plot these xaxis  is plotting with 24hrs time on it.

Resulting many gaps between day to day candles.

I need the chart without gaps between candles.
somebody help plz.[Need to plot the chart without these gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfc92.png)